# What 'mark' does a language leaves on a library that we need language bindings?

Tags: c, linux, opengl, binding

What mark does a language leaves on a compiled library that we need language bindings if we have call its functions from a different language?

object code looks 'language free' to me.

While learning OpenGL in c in Linux environment I have across language bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, all you have to do is think about the myriad of calling conventions in C and C++. In order to prevent serious mishaps, the compiler mangles the function names based on calling convention so that you do not accidentally call a `stdcall` function using `fastcall` conventions. Each language has its own set of superfluous details like this that a language independent API should never have to burden itself with. Language bindings serve as an adapter/bridge that separates the language-specific stuff from the standardized API, filling in the gaps wherever necessary.

The OpenGL API is generally implemented in a single language (C) and programs written in other languages interface with the system's implementation through language bindings. OpenGL uses null-terminated ASCII strings for GLSL and has numerous functions that use pointers, things that make perfect sense for an API that is designed to be implemented in C. In Java, strings are not null-terminated and they are UTF-16 encoded; you can see why a bridge is needed. The Java GL bindings take care of string conversion and alter `glVertexPointer (...)`-like functions to fit Java's conditions for "pointing to" contiguous blocks of memory.

Answer (score 3):

> Binding provides a simple and consistent way for applications to present and interact with data.

Source: The tag under your question

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're either young or haven't been programming for more than a decade or so.

Object code should look language free, but it ain't due to history. Back in the 1970s and 1980s, on Intel 80x86 and Motorola 680x0 CPUs, function call arguments were passed on the stack. In the 'Pascal' convention, the number of arguments was fixed and the called function code removed them from the stack before returning. In the 'C' convention, the number of arguments was variable (eg printf) so the calling code had to remove them when the function returned. This cost 2 extra bytes per function call, which is nothing today but was significant back then when PCs only came with 128K or so of RAM. So Microsoft chose to use the Pascal calling convention for the Windows API, even though it was written in C. If your object code called a Windows function with the C convention by mistake, kaboom. This is why the header files are still cluttered up with WINAPI and _stdcall and _fastcall and whatnot.

Starting in the 1990s operating system authors realized this was silly and started imposing standard calling conventions on everyone. The C convention could handle both cases, so it got used everywhere. With the moves to MacOS X, 64 bit Windows, and ARM; we are finally getting language free object code.

Now, OpenGL was designed to be used from C and Fortran. (Which was in the 1990s still an important language for scientific calculations and visualization.) Both languages have integers, floating point numbers, and arrays of various sized ints/floats. C has structs but Fortran doesn't, and I suspect this is a major reason why the OpenGL API never uses any structs. There are also differences in the memory layout of 2D or higher dimension arrays between C and Fortran, and again note that the OpenGL API never specifies 2D arrays, only 1D.

A C API works for most languages. This is partly because C is 'portable assembler' that works onto almost any CPU and operating system. It's also because most other programming languages in common use are either supersets of C (C++, Objective-C) or implemented in C themselves (Python, Perl, Ruby) so can be made to call the OpenGL C API reasonably easily.

Java and C# have more problems, because they define their own object code, so to speak, and memory access is more tightly controlled. The C/OpenGL notion of 'here is a pointer to a block of memory, do what you like with it' breaks the security model of the JVM/CLR. So you end up having to use Java NIOByteBuffer things instead of just passing arrays.

A lot of it also comes down to the skill of the language binding designer. For one example, Python-OpenGL by Mike Fletcher is a really good binding. All the functions and constants have exactly the same names, so a lot of code can be just copied from C and pasted into Python. Python doesn't have C style arrays directly, but the language binding will silently translate any Python sequences/tuples you pass as "arrays" into the underlying C format for you. It feels natural for a Python programmer and still exposes the full capabilities of OpenGL.

For a bad example, JOGL is a pain in the arse. There's no automatic conversion from Java arrays to C, so you have to futz around with NIOByteBuffers yourself. It's so annoying that it's actually easier to use glBegin..glEnd blocks. And extra array offset arguments got added to a lot of OpenGL functions, so your code no longer looks the same as C/C++ and you waste a lot of time sticking ,0 on the end of function calls. Some of this is due to the JVM as mentioned before, but a lot of it is just bad design by (I suspect) somebody who never actually wrote much OpenGL themselves.

A long and rambling answer to a vague question.